# Why is this background image fade in plugin deleting out the content of my div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I am using the [jQuery bgFade Plugin](http://isthatclear.com/jquery/bgFade/) and it fades the background image nicely but there's a problem with it. It deletes everything that is in the div when you hover. You can see it here: http://weebuild1.yolasite.com/ (hover over the first box that says "Packages")

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.packages').hover(function() {
$(this).bgFade('fadeIn');
}, function() {
$(this).bgFade('fadeOut');
});
});
</script>
```

Can someone help me fix this issue? As you all know, this cannot stay like this. It needs to only fade the background and not remove the contents.

The plugin's jQuery is here: http://weebuild1.yolasite.com/resources/javascript/jquery.bgFade.js

I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it actually deleting the content of the div, or does the image just appear over the top of the content? Methinks what you need here is [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)... ;-)

Comment: @Dave It looks like it is deleting the content as when I take my mouse off, it doesn't come back. I will try z-index, thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @Dave I just tried z-index... still didn't work :(

Comment: According to the web page provided within the question. The `h1` and `p` are removed during hover. Doesn't make any sense to me at this point.

Comment: @Lollero I am confused too. This is very odd. And annoying. Hopefully someone else will know a fix to this issue.

Comment: By the way.. i find it super weird that this plugin requires you to put `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`. I would understand it, if the plugin would do more than fade in and fade out but as i understand it doesnt. It's almost like if you had to tell your cellphone "You are a phone" before it starts functioning like a phone.

Comment: @Lollero LOL, that is weird. It should just be like `$('element').bgFade();` instead of having that `fadeIn` stuff. It was the only plugin that I could find though that does this sort of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might even just forget about the fade plugin and do something like this.

### Solution 1 ( uses `<img>` )

http://jsfiddle.net/yJHRA/3/ ( Should work ie6+. Not tested. )

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <img class="boxBG1" src="http://lorempixum.com/400/200/" alt="" />
    <img class="boxBG2" src="http://lorempixum.com/g/400/200/" alt="" />

    <div class="boxContent">
        <h1>Lipsum</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}

.boxBG1, .boxBG2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}
.boxBG1 { z-index: 5; }
.boxBG2 { z-index: 10; display: none; }

.boxContent {
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 15;

    color: #fff;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".box").each(function(){
        $(this).mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).find('.boxBG2').stop(false,true).fadeIn(400);
        });
        $(this).mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).find('.boxBG2').stop(false,true).fadeOut(400);
        });
    });

});
```

### Solution 2 ( uses background images)

http://jsfiddle.net/yJHRA/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="boxContent">
        <h1>Lipsum</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- the extra .box2 div is generated here. Not necessary but i thought.. why the heck not.. ( not necessary as in you could just add that div here manually as well.. ) -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box, .box2 {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}
.box {
    position: relative;
    background: url("http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/4026/firstr.jpg") no-repeat top left;
}
.box2 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    background: url("http://img840.imageshack.us/img840/5213/secondm.jpg") no-repeat top left;
    display: none;
}

.boxContent {
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".box").each(function(){
        $(this).append('<div class="box2" />');

        $(this).mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).find('.box2').stop(false,true).fadeIn(400);
        });
        $(this).mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).find('.box2').stop(false,true).fadeOut(400);
        });
    });

});
```

Edit: Added `.stop()`s so that if someone goes nuts with the hovering, the animation wont go nuts..

Edit2: forgot that you have multiple boxes.. Fixed..

Edit3: Added solution 2 which uses background images.

Comment: Thanks, but these are `<img>`'s. What about the background images? (I like background images better than using regular images on stuff like this.)

Comment: I couldn't get it all to work properly, but it's fine :) I'm just adding the text into the background images now in Photoshop and using the bgFade plugin. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

From what I can gather from the javascript code, it seems that this line actually removes all content except the link from the faded div:

```
fader.siblings().not('a').remove();
```

A simple solution would be to actually move the content to an adjacent div and overlay it using positioning.

```
<div class="box packages">
       <a class="box-link" href="packages.php">Packages</a>
       <h2>Packages</h2>
       <p>We have three different packages available. Get the package that's just right for you!</p>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="box packages">
           <a class="box-link" href="packages.php">Packages</a>
    </div>
    <div class="packages text">
           <h2>Packages</h2>
           <p>We have three different packages available. Get the package that's just right for you!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.holder {
  position: relative;
}

.holder .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; /* adjust accordingly */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't I just remove that line to stop the script from doing that?

Comment: The bgFade plugin has a lot of problems actually. It adds it's own link into it that goes to google.com. So I will not be using that plugin it looks like.

Comment: @Nathan I wouldn't recommend simply removing that line. I suggest delving into the code and draw inspiration for your own script. It would be an enlightening learning experience :D

Comment: Yeah, I actually ended up just adding the text into the graphic itself (and now I got to use a custom non-web-safe font on it) so I wont have to worry about the content getting wiped out. Thanks for your help! I will look into writing my own script :)